# Is $\mathcal P(A \cap B) \subseteq \mathcal P(A) \cap \mathcal P(B)$ for all sets A and B?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My question is: Is  $\mathcal P(A \cap B) \subseteq \mathcal P(A) \cap \mathcal P(B)$ for all sets A and B?

I'm pretty lost on this but I have tried to solve it and I need some help. Let's say $A=\{1, 2, 3\}$ and $B=\{2, 3, 4\}$

Then $\mathcal P(A \cap B) = \mathcal P(\{2, 3\})=\{ \{\emptyset\}, \{2, 3\}, \{2\}, \{3\} \}$

And $\mathcal P(A) \cap \mathcal P(B)=\mathcal P(\{ \{\emptyset\}, \{1, 2, 3\}, \{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 3\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\} \})\cap\mathcal P(\{ \{\emptyset\}, \{2, 3, 4\}, \{2, 3\}, \{2, 4\}, \{3, 4\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\} \})=\{ \{\emptyset\},\{2, 3\}, \{2\}, \{3\} \}$

Does this mean that the original statement is true? If so, how can we prove that it's true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot prove anything in Mathematics by  just giving one example.

Comment: I know, that is why I'm asking for help...

Comment: I will change the post

Comment: In words you ask: "is every subset of $A\cap B$ a subset of $A$ and of $B$? And this for all sets $A$ and $B$?" For proving $X\subseteq Y$ it is enough to prove that $x\in X$ implies that $x\in Y$. Apply that on $X=\mathcal P(A\cap B)$ and $Y=\mathcal P(A)\cap\mathcal P(B)$.

Comment: @drhab I don't understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Start with $x\in\mathcal P(A\cap B)\implies x\subseteq A\cap B\implies\cdots$ and end with $\cdots\implies x\in\mathcal P(A)\cap\mathcal P(B)$. Then you are ready.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a set $S$ in $\mathcal{P}(A\cap B)$. For any $s\in S$, we must have $s\in A\cap B$, so in particular $s\in A$. But this shows that all elements of $S$ are also elements of $A$. Therefore, $S\in\mathcal{P}(A)$. Similarly, you can show that $S\in\mathcal{P}(B)$. Combining these two results you find $S\in\mathcal{P}(A)\cap\mathcal{P}(B)$.